# Positional argument in arparse

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following code which takes exactly three arguments. The user needs to provide all the three arguments. This is the order of the arguments that needs to be supplied at the command line when running the script.
    browser
    username
    password.

## Name of the program Argparse.py

```
import argparse
import sys
from collections import OrderedDict
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('browser', default='chrome', help='This is the browser type, browser type:chrome,'
                    'firefox or ie')
parser.add_argument('username', help='This is the  username')
parser.add_argument('password', help='This is the  password')
args = parser.parse_args()
parser.print_help()
print(args.browser)
browsers = ['chrome', 'firefox', 'ie']
if args.browser not in browsers:
    print("invalid browser")
```

If a user forgot to specify the browser argument and runs the script with just two arguments(username and password), the script should throw an error saying that the browser argument is missing but instead in my case the script throws an error saying the password is missing. How do I specify that the first positional should always be the browser type>

```
Output :

    C:\>python Argparse.py user pass

    usage: Argparse.py [-h] browser username password
    Argparse.py: error: the following arguments are required: password
```

Any suggestions would help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to tell the `parser` that the first argument `browser` is optional (indicated with `-` and `--` prefixes), otherwise it expects the first required positional argument to be the `browser` argument.

Make `browser` optional by prefixing it with `-` or `--`:

```
parser.add_argument('-b', '--browser', default='chrome', help='This is the browser type, browser type:chrome,'
                    'firefox or ie')
```

runs:

```
$ python Argparse.py user pass
chrome
user
pass
```